# TCPDF ImageSVG picture rotation

Tags: svg, tcpdf, image-rotation

I want to know if its a bug, or im doing something wrong. Can someone confirm it before i report it to the writer?

the SVG (file.svg):

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1226" version="1.1" height="826"><image transform="matrix(1.0364,-0.3305,0.3305,1.0364,-41.846,108.0143)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="10" y="10" width="205" height="154" xlink:href="wallpaper.jpg" opacity="1" stroke-width="1"></image><rect transform="matrix(1.0364,-0.3305,0.3305,1.0364,-41.846,108.0143)" x="165" y="114" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#000" opacity="0" stroke-width="1"></rect><image transform="matrix(1.1575,0.2385,-0.2385,1.1575,-442.1395,-145.4163)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="500" y="10" width="205" height="154" xlink:href="wallpaper.jpg" opacity="1" stroke-width="1"></image><rect transform="matrix(1.1575,0.2385,-0.2385,1.1575,-442.1395,-145.4163)" x="655" y="114" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#000" opacity="0" stroke-width="1"></rect></svg>
```

the PHP code:

```
require_once('../config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='file.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
$pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'F');
```

The svg file looks fine in the browser but in thefinished PDF the images sides have problem: they look like a saw:

http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/816/pdfproof.jpg

Comment: What is PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO. What happens when you increase it? I believe there is a setImageScale that you could try altering too e.g. pdf->setImageScale(1.53);

Comment: Unfortunately it has nothing to do with the problem.TCPDF::setImageScale($scale) 
Set the adjusting factor to convert pixels to user units. = it makes the pictures bigger/smaller

Comment: Is this definitely a TCPDF problem? Can you generate a similar PDF using InDesign or Illustrator and see if it appears the same? I've not used TCPDF, but from my experience elsewhere older versions of the PDF specification had no or poor antialiasing (that's the effect that removed the 'saw' edges). Check your Acrobat view settings or try saving as a more recent version of PDF if it's an older format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='file.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
```

I think on the above line you has a mistake the `$file='file.svg'` usually needs to open the file and store it in variable and parse the variable with the below format:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG('@'. $svgString1, $x=15, $y=$line, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='center', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
```

where `$svgString1` is my SVG image from the post of HTML